# how do I set a variable to get value from Firebase database structure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am now struggling with Firebase database.

For example here's my database structure

```
"Menus" : {
"Day1" : {
  "mealDes" : "delicious Thai food",
  "date" : "2016.10.20",
  "mealname" : "kakoon"
},
```

and I need to set a variable to get the value of "date".

something like :  print(theDateVar)  //get 2016.10.20

I tried some observeSingleEvent and observe method, they're not working!

```
DataService.ds.REF_MENUS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            if let date = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "menuDate") as? String {

                print ("date is \(date)")

            }

        })
```

I know retrieving data from database is frequently asked, 
but all the question i searched is not helping

please help me out :(, I spend half of my weekend on this but still...

**UPDATE**

Hi, it totally worked!

my code now is looks like the following :

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Menus/Day1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

            if let snapDict = snap.value as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject>{

                let date = snapDict["mealPic"] as! String


                let OrderInfo = DataService.ds.REF_ORDER
                let USERUID = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
                let userinfo = OrderInfo.child("date").child(USERUID).child("data")

                userinfo.child("address").setValue("SomeRandomAddress")
                userinfo.child("phonenumber").setValue("666888")
            }
        })
```

but what if I want to set the address value and the phone number value as the value i have in other node (user)

```
"Menus": {
"User" : {
"WbxT2bBgcnYOEn2YUqpvh4mtxvo2" : {
  "address" : "taipei City ",
  "phonenumber" : "0933555666",
  "provider" : "Firebase"
}
```

do i use observeSingleEvent again in observeSingleEvent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :-

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("menus/Day1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

        print(snap)

        if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            let date = snapDict["date"] as! String
            print(date)

        }
    })
```

Comment: hi Dravidian, it worked thanks. I update my question you might want take a glance

Comment: @Ian Avoid extending questions in comments , post other question on SO, surely some1 will help....